# Typescript interface modify nested Object property Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

im working on a angular project with typescript , this is my model :

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    dateValid:string;
    commentList: Comment[];
}

export interface Comment {
    id: number;
    issueDate: string;
}
```

and this is my service before save my user object , i need to format dates ..

```
   saveUser(user: User) {
     let userToSave: User = { ...user };
     this.prepareUserBeforeSave(userToSave);
    }



 prepareUserBeforeSave(user: User) {
     
   let listOfComments: any { ...user, commentList: user.commentList.map(comment=>({...comment})) }
        //format Dates
        user.dateValid = user.dateValid == '' ? '' : this.datePipe.transform(user.dateValid, DATE_DD_MM_YYYY);
    
        for (let index = 0; index < listOfComments.length; index++) {
            listOfComments[index].dueDate = listOfComments[index].issueDate == '' ? '' : this.datePipe.transform(listOfComments[index].issueDate, DATE_DD_MM_YYYY);
        }
    
    }
```

but im getting the following error : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'` in this line : `user.commentList[index] = formatedComment;`

how i can format correctly the list of my nested object

Comment: From where do you get the user? Is it from `ngrx` ?

Comment: @Wandrille this.saveUser(myreactivForm.value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `{ ...user }`, it will create a new instance for the item inside the user. But not deep inside.

So if you want to create a deeper copy, you should do:

```
let userToSave: User ={ ...user, commentList: user.commentList.map(comment=>({...comment})) };
```

Comment: thanks for you response , but im getting the same error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'issueDate' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: I have updated my answer. When you do {...user}, it doesn't create a deep copy. So you keep the reference in your list

Comment: it doesn't work , my dates are not formatted. i updated my question

Comment: I have updated the answer. I believe it's only a matter of cloning.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this does not answer the question directly, but I hope it is quite helpful.

1. You have a very uncommon (and unsafe) way to save comments. Your code is running on frontend-side. This means that people with know-how can change their comments (including timestamps).
2. The comments are part of your user. That does not scale very well, because each time you fetch a user, you will fetch all comments. The user object will grow over time and introduce a bad performance.
3. The dates are strings. Typescript allows you to be type-safe.
4. You used the date-pipe directly in your code. The pipe are meant to use in template.

A better design could look like this:

```
// interfaces

export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    dateValid: Date;
    commentList: Comment[];
}

export interface Comment {
    id: number;
    issueDate: Date;
    text: string;
}


// methods

public saveUser(user: User): void {
    // your safe logic - perhaps calling a service
}

public addComment(comment: string) {
    // call your backend over a service
    // don't let frontend decide who owns the comment
    // the backend has to decide that
    // also let backend decide the timestamp, otherwise users can inject other dates
}

public getComments$(userId: number): Observable<Comments[]> {
    // fetch comments separately to the user
}
```

In your template, you can show it like this:

```html
<span>Name: {{ currentUser.name }}</span>
</br>
<span>Comments:</span>
<ng-container *ngIf="getComments(currentUser.id) | async as comments">
   <div *ngFor="let comment of comments">
      <span>{{ comment.text }}</span>
      </ br>
      <span>written {{ comment.issueDate }}</span>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thank you so much. i will take in consideration your recommendation . i highly appreciate it.